# Installing brew from macOS app's pre/postinstall script

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, post-install

In my [`Packages.app`](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html)'s `preinstall` script I was able to install brew from a modified version of brew's `install.sh` that removed the `sudo` check:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
##preinstall

if brew ls --versions wget > /dev/null; then
  # The package is installed
  osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "The package is installed"'
else
  # The package is not installed
  osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "The package is not installed"'
    
  /usr/bin/su root -c ./brew-install.sh

fi

exit 0
```

This is the line I removed from brew's `install.sh` to get this to work:

```sh
if [[ "${EUID:-${UID}}" == "0" ]]; then
```

I don't know what `"${EUID:-${UID}}"` is exactly.

This is what I've tried so far unsuccessfully instead of using `su root`:

```sh
# /bin/bash -c ./brew-install.sh

# sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a $USER -t user admin
# sudo /usr/bin/su $USER -c ./brew-install.sh

# /usr/bin/su ladmin -c ./brew-install.sh

# nohup /usr/bin/su $USER -c /bin/bash -c ./brew-install.sh &
```

Notably trying to add `$USER` to `admin` group from here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/76096/261453

---

Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Brew without root by using the "untar install" option for brew:
[Why brew installation needs sudo access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487746/why-brew-installation-needs-sudo-access#comment117539341_66487746)

See Brew docs here:
https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere

If Brew is still blocking for `root` reasons you can modify `Library/Homebrew/bin/brew.sh` to remove the `root` check and then from `postinstall`, `rm` the existing `brew.sh` and replace if with your copy that you added in `Packages.app`'s Script's Addition Resources:

[image: Packages.app Script Addition Resources]